# Java CRC32 calculation in a multi threading envirinment

Tags: java, multithreading, crc32

I have a following util class for crc32 calculation:

```
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import java.util.zip.Checksum;

public class StringUtils {

    public static long crc32(String input) {
        byte[] bytes = input.getBytes();
        Checksum checksum = new CRC32();
        checksum.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

        return checksum.getValue();
    }

}
```

Performance is a very important criterion for me.

Right now I'm thinking on a possible refactoring of this method and I'm thinking to move `checksum` to a class level as a static field... something like this:

```
public class StringUtils {

    public static Checksum checksum = new CRC32();

    public static long crc32(String input) {
        byte[] bytes = input.getBytes();
        checksum.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

        return checksum.getValue();
    }

}
```

but I'm not sure will it correctly work in a concurrent multithreading environment. Please advise - such kind of refactoring it's a good idea or not.

Comment: You shouldn't do that because, even ignoring multithreading, `getValue` doesn't reset the CRC32 data fed in during previous calls to `crc32`. You'd need to use the [`reset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/CRC32.html#reset--) method either at the beginning or end of the `crc32` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others have said, CRC32 isn't thread-safe, so you'd have to either synchronize or use a ThreadLocal, but those aren't especially likely to help.

If you look the implementation of [CRC32](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/zip/CRC32.java.html), is has *one* field. Before you do anything, benchmark your code. Between Java's complicated GC, JIT, and escape analysis, it's hard to predict if you'll see any benefit.

Rewriting this to avoid array allocation might give you a bigger benefit:

```
byte[] bytes = input.getBytes();
```

Edit: please don't do this unless you absolutely have to.

This unrolls String's internal `getBytes()` to avoid some intermediate buffering and takes advantage of CRC32 having an optimization for direct byte buffers:

```
public class StringUtils {
    private static final ThreadLocal<ByteBuffer> BUFFER = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4094));

    public static long crc32(String input) {
        CharBuffer inputBuffer = CharBuffer.wrap(input);
        ByteBuffer buffer = BUFFER.get();
        CRC32 crc32 = new CRC32();
        CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.defaultCharset().newEncoder();

        CoderResult coderResult;
        do {
            try {
                coderResult = encoder.encode(inputBuffer, buffer, true);
                buffer.flip();
                crc32.update(buffer);
            } finally {
                buffer.reset();
            }
        } while (coderResult.isOverflow());

        return crc32.getValue();
    }
}
```

You might be able to do even better by manually doing the encoding (which is trivial for ASCII). What complicates performance is balancing copying bytes into a buffer just to read them out with the JNI call to the actual CRC32 implementation. The intermediate buffer could actually be faster because of JNI overhead. Be sure to read up on [direct bytebuffers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#direct) before doing this; if you aren't actually reusing the buffer, this could be slow.

When you actually dig into what's going on, you'll find that `getBytes()` is much more complicated than you realize, and worrying about the allocation of a trivial, short-lived CRC32 object isn't a major contributor to performance.

Comment: Right now, you're using the default encoding. Can you safely assume ASCII?

Answer (score 4):

No, your code is not thread safe. Fortunately, you can make it become thread safe with one simple class and hardly any performance loss:

[`ThreadLocal<Checksum>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) is your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously you can't do so in multi-thread environment, because `CRC32` class is not thread-safe.

Short answer: it is not thread-safe, because its javadoc doesn't contain this hint.

More detailed: if you will open source of `CRC32` class, you will see, that this class doesn't contain any synchronisation blocks, it is not atomic, and contain object variable

```
private int crc;
```

which is not synchronized.

**UPD:** But you can use `ThreadLocal<Checksum>` as @Dariusz [suggested in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42191787/1479414).